# How to open url in messaging extension?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have updated my bot builder package from 4.6.0 to 4.9.0 i.e., the latest version.
We have `handleTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTask` method which returns a promise. The return type is changed in version 4.9.0. The return type right now is the Promise of `MessagingExtensionActionResponse`.
With this return type, there is no way indicated in the documentation regarding opening a URL.
I have added the return type I was using in version 4.6.0 and that was working fine but it seems like there's no way in current update for performing such operations.

```
return await {
    task: {
        type: 'continue', value: {
            width: 450,
            height: 600,
            title: 'Abc'
            url: '********',
            fallbackUrl: '*******'
        }
    }
} as MessagingExtensionActionResponse;
```

Comment: **Thank You** for accepting answer, this will help others in the community with similar question. Could you please spare one min to let us know how we did by clicking on **[this feedback link](https://aka.ms/DevSupportFeedback)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initiate a message extension with open action URL. Please find the below piece of code

```cs
protected override async Task<MessagingExtensionActionResponse> OnTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTaskAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, MessagingExtensionAction action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var response = new MessagingExtensionActionResponse()
    {
        Task = new TaskModuleContinueResponse()
        {
            Value = new TaskModuleTaskInfo()
            {
                Height = 720,
                Width = 900,
                Title = "Testing ME with URL,
                Url = "https://1f0bd229.ngrok.io/myPage"
            },
        },
    };
    
    return response;
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't help you out

Comment: I wrote my code in nodeJS. The similar response type I was using earlier when I was using package 4.6.0 and that was working pretty fine but not working on 4.9.0.